# PHP Sockets in Realtime

Tags: php, sockets

**Background**

A desktop application on a user's computer gets the phone number from the modem and sends it to a PHP script once a phone call is recieved. At the moment, I am able to receive the data/packet on the specified port via PHP. I then have a scraper that connects to 411 databases and returns the address for the specified phone number.

**Problem**

After I retrieve the phone number in PHP through sockets, how can I automatically update the 411 parser page with the new phone number?

**Code**

**socket_listener.php**

```
set_time_limit(0);

$address = "127.0.0.1";
$port    = 10629;

// create socket and bind with listener event

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, $address, $port);
socket_listen($socket);

do {
    $accept = socket_accept($socket);
    $read   = socket_read($accept, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

    // parse phone number
    $phone  = substr($read, 19, 15);    

    $file = fopen("phone_numbers.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, $phone . "\r\n");
    fclose($file);

} while (true);
```

**phone_numbers.txt**

```
(425) 555-1212
(123) 456-7890
```

**Current Solution**

My current solution is pretty quirky.

```
modem -> desktop application -> socket_listener.php -> data.txt -> 411_scraper.php
```

1. **socket_listener.php** listens on the port for incoming packets 24/7 and appends new phone numbers it receives to a text file
2. **411_scraper.php** checks text file for updates every 5 seconds. If file version is changed, then it reads the last phone number
3. Run code to query 411.com and retrieve data using phone number

**Desired Solution**

1. **socket_listener.php** listens on port for incoming packet containing phone number
2. Page automatically updates with new data retrieved from 411

**Things I've Been Looking At**

I've looked at node.js, Ratchet (www.socketme.com), and Pusher (http://pusher.com/) but they are all above my level of understanding. Pusher and Ratchet seems promising but I have not jumped into them yet.

Comment: Maybe you can create a callback for your socket_listener.php?

Comment: What's the problem specifically?  Why not just update that database directly within your `socket_listener.php`?

Comment: @Brad - The problem is is how do I make it so that once PHP receives the packet (phone number), then the page automatically queries the 411 database and outputs the data without having to go through a middle man like a text file. I've been doing more research and came across Ajax long polling method. Coupled with your suggestion to use a database instead

Comment: [Continued] Coupled with your suggestion to use a database instead, I could just update a table with new phone nums and timestamps and then poll the table every few seconds. I will be servicing about 10 businesses or so. Do you believe that it would be stressful on the server / cpu? I am guessing it shouldn't even scratch the server, but I will stress test to make sure.

Comment: Exactly.  I don't see the problem.  You're saying that the problem is you don't want PHP to write to a text file... I'm asking why you went that route in the first place?  Simply don't write to the text file and go straight to your database.  Or are you saying you don't have a database?  If that is the case, what does 411_scraper.php do?  Your description is that it reads a text file, but what is running it?  What does it do with that data?  Please be much more complete in your descriptions... as it stands now, your question is very confusing to me.

Comment: And as far as polling a database table goes, it is impossible to tell you if it will be a large load as I have no idea what your data looks like, or even what database server you are using.  If you only have a few (<10,000 records), you don't need to do anything.  I would add a date column for last updated, and query for anything since the last query.  You could also consider something like Redis where your database can be in memory, but written to disk as well for persistent storage.

Comment: @Brad There won't be a lot of data, just a two column table with phone numbers received and their timestamps. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

I would use ajax or something along those lines. PHP isn't a real time thing. When you navigate to a website which uses PHP the code is executed before the page is rendered. It's processing the code on the server computer and giving you back the result as a string which you can send to the requesting client.

You're going to have the hold the data somewhere persistently. Once the php script is done executing the data is for that execution gone. Unless you use sessions.